# Controller for removing an entity not fetching the id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this controller method

```
        [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult DeleteMake(int id)
    {
        var data = _dbContext.VehicleMake.Find(id);
        return View(data);
    }
```

I generated a delete view for it. I assumed that based on the entity I clicked delete on, it would get it's information. It doesn't. I don't know why. The id in the parameter is always 0. Interesting enough, if you type in something like .../DeleteMake/1, then it works on the id of 1. Just doesn't work with the view.

This is the view

```
@model Data.Entities.VehicleMakeEntity

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "DeleteMake";
}
<h2>DeleteMake</h2>
<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
<h4>VehicleMakeEntity</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Abrv)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Abrv)
    </dd>
</dl>

<form asp-action="DeleteMake">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</form>
```

And the method I use to actually list all the items

```
                private readonly IQueryable<VehicleMakeEntity> _source;

    public MakeRepository(ProjectDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        _source = this.context.VehicleMake;
    }
        public IEnumerable<VehicleMakeEntity> SelectListMake(int index, int count, Expression<Func<VehicleMakeEntity, int>> orderLambda)
    {
        return _source.Skip(index * count).Take(count).OrderBy(orderLambda);
    }
```

Comment: Your form does not post back anything. Either add a route value for the ID in the `<form>` or add a hidden input for the ID

Comment: I don't see in the code where the view is passing the ID to delete....

Comment: How would I do that @StephenMuecke?

Comment: Your could add `asp-route-id="@Model.Id"` in the `<form>` element, or add a hidden input - `<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />` or `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)`

Comment: I just tried it. The third one doesn't error out but the issue is still the same. `    <form asp-action="DeleteMake">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" asp-route-id="@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)"  class="btn btn-default" /> |
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List </a>
    </form>`

Comment: That has no relationship to my comment - read it carefully :)

Comment: `<form asp-action="DeleteMake" asp-route-id=Model.Id>` **OR** add a hidden input between the form tags

Comment: I'm sorry, trying my best to understand.
`<form asp-action="DeleteMake" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" />|
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to List </a>
    </form>`
Is that correct? Now it errors out on line 34: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I do not know what line 34 is. Have you passed a model to your view? Is it `null`?

Comment: Line 34 is that line `<form asp-action="DeleteMake" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">`. The full view can be seen in the OP, if by passing a model you mean the first line then yes. It recognizes that the Id is from the VehicleMakeEntity model.

Comment: The only way that error can possibly occur based on the code in your comment is if `Model` is `null` (and to test it, use `asp-route-id="1"`)

Comment: The only thing I found to be null is the data variable in the controller (see in op), so since it returns View(data) that could cause the null error. I tried using `var data = _dbContext.VehicleMake.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();` but data is still null.

Comment: You will also need to add `method="get"` (by default it will be a post)

Comment: But since its a get, why use a form - you can just create a link

Comment: I tested it, no errors changing it to "1", but data is still null and it doesn't work. Should it not work on the item with id 1?